# How to find difference of two string collections using Linq in c#

Tags: c#, string, linq

I do have one collection of string which tends to be like this

```
String []A = {4,5,6,7,8,9}
```

and there is another list of string 
`String []B= {6,7}`.

So, I want to find Difference of these strings.

```
A Difference B  = {4,5,8,9}
```

**How to do this using LINQ. I can do this using conventional checking child string in parent string and then build new string collection of not found items. But I want to get it done using linq**

Comment: what happend to `8`, Its neither in `B` nor in the result

Comment: Hi, this is not a string {4,5,6,7,8,9,10}. Do you mean this "{4,5,6,7,8,9,10}"?

Comment: I seek your apologizes

Comment: @YogeshJoshi I corrected in my answer `a` and `b`. Now they are both list of strings. (4,5,6,...are integer literals. That being said, {4,5,6,7} can be an array of integers or a list of integers etc. and not an array or a list of strings)

Comment: @YogeshJoshi you are welcome !

Answer (score 3):

It is extremely simple.

```
A.Except(B)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```
var a = new List<string> { "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" };
var b = new List<string> { "6", "7" };
var result = a.Except(b);
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can like this

```
var result = A.Where(i => !B.Any(t => t == i));
```